# Shutting down the Jacoco Java agent via tcp command

Tags: java, jacoco, tcpserver

Based on my research online, I see that only dump and reset commands can be sent to a Jacoco agent running as a tcpserver or client.

Are there any other commands that can be sent? Specifically, is there a command that can be used to shut down the Jacoco agent so that it stops instrumentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any other commands that can be sent?

As of today for the latest released version 0.7.9 there is no other commands - https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/v0.7.9/org.jacoco.core/src/org/jacoco/core/runtime/IRemoteCommandVisitor.java

> Specifically, is there a command that can be used to shut down the Jacoco agent so that it stops instrumentation?

And there is not way to stop/detach already started agent, stop collection of data from classes that are already instrumented, or restore original classes, stop further instrumentation of classes, etc.